# Not understanding basic property and methods in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, oop

I am new in Objective C but have some idea about Object Oriented Programming Language .

I have small doubt in the below code:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

UIColor *color;

switch (row) {
    case 1:
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.85 blue:2/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        break;
    case 2:
        color = [UIColor greenColor];
        break;
    case 3:
        color = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        break;
    default:
        color = [UIColor whiteColor];
        break;
}
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:color];

}
```

What I am doing here is just changing the background colour if some row of the picker view is selected.

Can someone explain the last line.

When I referred to the doc, I found that view and setBackgroundColor are property.

And we generally call methods like this

`[Object someMethod];`

So where are my concepts going wrong? Some links to the related concepts will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to change background color of the entire screen or only picker view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Properties were added to the language relatively recently (considering that Objective-C is more than three decades old). Whatever you can express with the dot syntax, you can also express using the "old-style" square bracket syntax. For example, if `view` is a property of `self`, these two ways of accessing it are equivalent:

```
self.view
```

and

```
[self view]
```

Therefore, your last line of code is equivalent to

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:color];
```

Same goes for setting properties, except by convention the `set` prefix and the initial capitalization are added to come up with the name of the setter. For example, if the property is called `backgroundColor`, then the setter would be called `setBackgroundColor:`

Therefore, you can rewrite the last line like this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = color;
```

Comment: Can you give analogy in some other language like Java. It would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @JayPatel There is no clean analogy in Java: Java Beans have a convention on getters and setters for properties, yet there is no language syntax to back that up. In other words, adding `int getX()` and `void setX(int val)` to a class in Java does *not* let you write `myObj.x = 123`, because getters and setters need to be called explicitly. However, there are tools that "understand" this convention (e.g. [NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansJavaBeansTutorial)). Other tools follow this convention as well - e.g. hibernate can recognize getters and setters, and treat them as one property.

Answer (score 3):

What concept are you having a problem with?

`self` is an object.
`[self view]` returns an view object.

```
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:color];
```

could be re-written:

```
UIView *aView = [self view];
[aView setBackgroundColor:color];
```

Comment: Ok thanks @Zaph. Are we just allowed to use "DOT" operator in accessing property or any other method access too? Any Resources for good tutorials on iOS and Objective C?

Comment: the dot is just syntax, it can be used with non properties. But it is best to restrict it to property-like usage, that is values, not method calls that have side-effects. So .count while not a property could be a property, feels like a property and makes sense.